Consultar campos de una tabla en un select de HTML utilizando Laravel
 La tabla "ligas" tiene sus registros ya, pero en la tabla "temporadas" hay un select que tendrá que mostrar todos los id registrados en "ligas", el campo se llama "IDLiga".
<select name="id_liga_temporadas" id="id_liga_temporadas">
    @foreach($ligas as $liga)
        <option value="{{ $liga->IDLiga }}">{{ $liga->IDLiga }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

Establecer metodo para guardar en el controlador (Comenté los demás campos en lo que hago funcionar el select):
public function guardarDatosFormTemporadas(Request $form){
        $temporada = new Temporada;

        $temporada -> IDTemporada = $form -> id_temporada;

        // $temporada -> Nombre = $form -> nombre_ampayers;
        // $temporada -> Apellidos = $form -> apellidos_ampayers;
        // $temporada -> FechaDeNacimiento = $form -> fnac_ampayers;
        // $temporada -> CURP = $form -> curp_ampayers;
        // $temporada -> Abreviacion = $form -> abreviacion_ampayers;
        // $temporada -> Estatus = $form -> estatus_ampayers;

        $temporada -> save();

        return redirect('/statsv6');
    }

Consulta de los campos:
    public function mostrarFormulario(){

        $ligas = Liga::all();
        return view('capturaDatos', ['ligas' => $ligas]);
    }

